# How to use Azure AD with OpenId Connect in a iFrame

Tags: iframe, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I've just been looking for hours for a way to call a web app in an iFrame that is protected with OpenId Connect SSO.

---

**Current status** is that either the following message appears with the link `https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc`.

[image]

Or the following error message with the link https://localhost:5001 :
[image]

If the application is called directly via the browser, then the login screen of Azure appears as desired. Only when I go via the iFrame, nothing works anymore. Even if I open the application first and log in, it does not work with iFrame.

---

**The settings** were made with the default template of Rider

[image]

csproj

```
...
<UserSecretsId>SomeGuideWithName</UserSecretsId>
<WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>0</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
...
```

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**appsettings.json**
xxx --> Secreds that are correct.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "xxx",
  "ClientId": "xxx",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using MitAuth.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    }
);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

---

Generated Cookies
[image]

---

**The goal** is to have application A (Caller) embed an iFrame that application B (OpenIdConnect protected).

Questions:

- Do I need to reconfigure anything in App B?
- Do I need to do anything else in App A?
- Is there any token or similar that has to be passed on?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? and samesite=none? Including cookies in iframes request is a problematic and should be avoided if possible in modern applications.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Yes I use HTTPS in both Applications. Currently, I do not control cookies at all. All I have done so far are the standard things used by the nuggets that are predefined by Microsoft. The iframe is a Blazor page and looks like this: `<iframe src="https://localhost:5001" width="900" height="500"></iframe>`

Comment: How is the cookie set? what attributes are used? samesite? secure?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I have now added it to the description. Secure=true and samesite=Lax

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment:***

I got the same error:

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
```

[image]

Here due to misconfiguration in callback path I got the error.
In your case check without giving callbackpath in both code and portal.

**Appsettings.json:**

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mytenantxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "fbxxxxxxxxxxxxf3b0",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/"
  },
```

I have configured following redirect urls in portal.

[image]

My application url uses ***`http protocol`***  `http://localhost:44328`

**Startup.cs**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

When I changed the CallbackPath value to /signin-oidc , that error was resolved.

Appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
    ...
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

Also check [Exception: Correlation failed. AAD + Azure Front Door](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063148/exception-correlation-failed-aad-azure-front-door)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, still does not work. I already had most of your configuration. I have entered the redirect path in the portal again. But now I get the message in the iFrame that localhost has closed the connection.